# Como usar mais de um DataSet em uma única tabela no Reporting Services

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

Boa tarde, gostaria de uma grande ajuda, estou tentando usar dois DataSets dentro de uma única tabela no Reporting Services. Alguém poderia me informar se há alguma forma de fazer tal ação?

Comment: Poderia adicionar o que tem tentando fazer e o problema que está enfrentando? Seja bem vindo ao Stack Overflow, recomendo a leitura no [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender um pouco mais de como funcionam as coias por aqui.